# What VST can generate beats like those in Bad Wings

Tags: beats, fl-studio, vst

I'm new to making music and I was listening to `Bad Wings by The Glitch Mob` and I wanted to know how these badass beats are generated. Are there any plugins (probably 3rd party) to generate the same sound in FL Studio? Or maybe there is a method to achieve the same sound that you know of?

It sounds like a music suitable for an action game and I love how each time the beat is hit it's long and epic. I can't describe it so I'd appreciate it if you could please just listen to it and help me out.

Comment: I think that you have to modify the delay and decay rates of the existing drum kit in FL Studio (I haven't used it, but that's what I feel will work well ). Sorry if this doesn't work.

Comment: I use LMMS, so I kinda find it hard to deal with FL Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `Drumpad` for the beats and `Fruity Reeverb 2` to make them sound closer to the desired sound. It's officially awesome!